# Htaccess compare a cookie name with a value in the database

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cookies

Is there any way that I can compare a cookie value to a string saved in the database in my htaccess . ? A string is a random key generated every time user logs in .

I want it to be like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !CookieName=Some-Cookie-Value-Script.php [NC] 
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/login.php [L]

// How do I check if CookieName value is equally to the one in the database 
// returned by Some-Cookie-Value-Script.php
```

Please help , I have tried all over Google and SO with no lucky ,

Comment: does not sound like something any one would (or should) want to do with an .htacess file

Comment: I dont know the value of a cookie,  how do I get it then

Comment: .htacess is not where you manage your user logins\authentication

Comment: Im not trying to manage users through htacces,  I only what the cookie value,  the rewrite rule is my initial test page and it can be changed,  my interest is only based on how to get the cookie value from the database

Comment: htaccess cannot query your database. It can extract the cookie value and pass it your .php file

Comment: This sounds like a nice idea,  how do i do that,  Im still a noob in htaccess @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform a database lookup in .htaccess (using PHP) in order to get the value to check for. .htaccess finishes long before PHP gets a chance to do anything.

What you can do in .htaccess is internally rewrite all requests to your PHP script which does the necessary lookup, checks the cookie and processes it accordingly. Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cookie-check\.php
RewriteRule .* /cookie-check.php [L]
```

For example... if you request `/somefile.php`, the above directives will rewrite this request to `/cookie-check.php`. The browser still shows `/somefile.php` in the browser address bar (this is an *internal rewrite*, not an *external redirect*). Then, in "cookie-check.php" you do something like:

```
<?php
$cookie = isset($_COOKIE['cookiename']) ? $_COOKIE['cookiename'] : null;
if ($cookie) {
    // The cookie is set, check that it is the expected value...
    // Perform database lookup to get expected cookie value
    $expectedCookie = '<value looked up from DB>';
    if ($cookie == $expectedCookie) {
        // The cookie is set and it is the expected value
        // Check $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] for the requested URL and load
        // the page as normal
        // ...

    } else {
        // The cookie exists but it is not the expected value
        // Redirect to "login.php"?
    }
} else {
    // The cookie does not exist at all
    // Redirect to "login.php"?
}
```

Comment: Please can you explain to me,  is the requested uri being checked against the cookie check php.?  and what / why    does rewrite rule do with cookie-check.php

Comment: The requested URL is being checked in order to avoid a rewrite-loop. The URL is not rewritten if the request is already pointing to `cookie-check.php`. All requests are sent to `cookie-check.php`, although the URL in the browser will remain on the originally requested URL and can be read in PHP using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Note that this is an "internal rewrite", not an "external redirect".

Comment: Thank you bro, this is exactly what I was looking for , I will try look more on internal and external rewrite concept .  Thank you again @w3d

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in an htaccess file. You'd have to redirect to a generic php page that checks the cookies value.